# My Junit5 xml report don`t have the <testsuites> tag

Tags: gradle, automated-tests, junit5

I need my reports to have the  tag but it appears directly with testsuite, does anyone know how to do this? Junit5 with Java and gradle. Thanks!

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf50g.png)

I create my testsuite run file and add the java classes